# In Sencha CMD, how to specify widget files absolute paths in the generated bootstrap.js?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I am new to Sencha Touch and the Sencha world. During `sencha app build` in development, I want to specity my server absolute url in the generated `bootstrap.js` so that the Sencha loader loads the widgets using the correct url.

How can I do this?

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want to utilize [paths configuration](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader-cfg-paths). This can and should be done in your application definition (app.js) by adding an array of paths. Here you can map a specific/custom class namespace to a URL path.

You will also want to add this to "classpath" in app.json.